# getting element id in React.js JSX rendering using .map() method

Tags: reactjs, dom

I am working on app using react,

```
const getButtonId=(num)=>{
   let click_detect=document.getElementById('div_'+num)
   console.log(click_detect)
}

this.state.users.map(i=>{
   return(
    <button id={'div_'+i.id} onClick={(i.id)=>this.getButtonId(i.id)}>
      Click Me
    </button>
  )
})
```

So every time I clicked on the button, I kept getting `null`. Why is that? If I want all buttons to have different id, What should I do here?

Comment: try this: `onClick={()=>this.getButtonId(i.id)}`, also don't forget to bind the `getButtonId` function inside your component's constructor

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const getButtonId = (id) => console.log("Button ID:", id);

this.state.users.map((user, index) => (
   <button key={index} onClick={() => this.getButtonId(user.id)}>
      Click Me
   </button>
))
```